# I am facing a TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Tags: python

```
def area_triangle(): # Function for area of triangle by herons formula
    a = float(input("Enter length of first side:"))
    b = float(input("Enter length of second side:"))
    c = float(input("Enter length of third side:"))
    s = (a + b + c)/2
    triangle = s*(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)**0.5
    print("Area of triangle =",triangle)
```

This is the block of code where I am facing the error

Comment: Besides missing the * between terms, another issue is you are only square rooting the last term rather than all of them. Formula (Heron's) should be triangle = (s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))**0.5 This is due to ** having higher precedence than *.

Answer (score 0):

```
triangle = s*(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)**0.5
```

Isn't correct in Python, multiplication isn'd carried out this way.

```
triangle = s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)**0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

your issue was with line 6.
you had `triangle = s*(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)**0.5`

it should be `triangle = s * ( s - a ) * ( s - b ) * ( s - c) ** 0.5`

you forgot to multiple your `( s - a )` and `( s - b )` and `( s - c )` with each other

without the `*` you were calling it as a function like `(1)(2)(3)` which would be interpreted as call function (1)(2) with the value of `3`, and call function (1) with the value of `2`

```py
def area_triangle(): # Function for area of triangle by herons formula
    a = float(input("Enter length of first side:"))
    b = float(input("Enter length of second side:"))
    c = float(input("Enter length of third side:"))
    s = float((a + b + c)/2.0)
    triangle = s * ( s - a ) * ( s - b ) * ( s - c)**0.5
    print("Area of triangle =",triangle)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put * between the parentheses in your triangle formula